# ToolValidator not doing anything

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, tool-validation

I have created a simple script tool which has a single parameter of type "String".  I have written the tool validation to disable the input field (simply trying to learn tool validation).  The validator code is as follows:

```
class ToolValidator:

  def __init__(self):
    import arcpy
    self.params = arcpy.GetParameterInfo()

  def initializeParameters(self):
    self.params[0].Enabled = 0
    return

  def updateParameters(self):
    return

  def updateMessages(self):
    return
```

Unfortunately, when I open the tool, the field is not disabled (as I expect it should be). Any ideas what I'm missing?

SOLUTION: In case it's not clear in the threads below.  The solution to the issue was to change Enabled to enabled, which is a case change between ArcGIS 9.3 and 10.0.  This capitalization works correctly both in the initializeParameters method and the updateMessages method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are putting it in the wrong spot.   This is how I've done it previously.

```
def updateMessages(self):
    self.params[0].enabled = False
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this didn't work either.

Comment: Not even when changing it from `Enabled` to `enabled` (note case)?

Comment: +1, just noticed that you are also using the lowercase `enabled`.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution. thanks all. love a good case switch between versions :). Jason, if you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I think this actually needs to go in `updateParameters`, not `updateMessages`.

Comment: Please accept BmoreGeo's answer, he has the correct case in his code.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get it running by using `enabled` instead of `Enabled`.

Here is a link that lists all of the available params properties (they show lowerCamelCase for all of the properties): [Programming a ToolValidator class](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00150000000v000000.htm)

Comment: I just noticed +Jason Scheirer's comment.